# ng-switch + function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Boa tarde, estou tentando usar o `ng-switch` para mostrar um valor que depende de uma condição que está em uma função, porem só consigo passar valores fixos para o campo, a função com `if` parece que não repassa o valor, caso não fique claro, segue o exemplo no codepen.

```
$scope.value1='0';
  $scope.condition = function(){
    if($scope.value1>=10){
      return $scope.value=200;
    }
  }
```

http://codepen.io/haykou/pen/zqndw

Comment: Me parece um [ProblemaXY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1202/70). Teria como explicar o efeito final desejado? Clique em [edit] e acrescente detalhes relevantes se for possível.

Comment: Sim, no caso do primeiro switch se eu digitar 1 no input, ele vai mostrar 1 abaixo e no segundo eu queria criar uma condição, no exemplo gostaria de digitar qualquer numero maior que 10 e a div abaixo mostrasse o valor 200 
    <div ng-switch-when="1" >1</div>
    <div ng-switch-when="condition()" >2</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traduzindo uma parte da [documentação do ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch):

> Esteja ciente que os valores do atributo [`ng-switch-when`] não podem ser [expressões](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). Os valores são interpretados como literais para serem comparados.

Ou seja, quando você utiliza `ng-switch-when="condition()"`, o angular esta tentando comparar o valor do atributo `ng-switch` com a string `condition()` ao invés de chamar a função.

No seu caso, eu utilizaria o [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) e o [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) para exibir uma condição alternativa à do `ng-switch`:

```
<body ng-app ng-controller='controller'>
    <label>Type a value: <input type="text" ng-model="value" /></label><br />
    <div ng-switch="value" ng-hide="condition()">
        <div ng-switch-when="1">1</div>
        <div ng-switch-when="3">3</div>
        <div ng-switch-when="4">4</div>
        <div ng-switch-when="5">5</div>
        <div ng-switch-default>None</div>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="condition()">2</div>
</body>
```

Também é possível fazer isso dentro do `ng-switch-default`:

```
<body ng-app ng-controller='controller'>
    <label>Type a value: <input type="text" ng-model="value" /></label><br />
    <div ng-switch="value">
        <div ng-switch-when="1">1</div>
        <div ng-switch-when="3">3</div>
        <div ng-switch-when="4">4</div>
        <div ng-switch-when="5">5</div>
        <div ng-switch-default>
            <div ng-show="condition()">2</div>
            <div ng-hide="condition()">None</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```